# JS calculting width and height for rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

am trying to draw rectangles it different angles , initially i know rectangle position data it 0 degree , then sometime i get angle greater than 0 so i have to draw on that angle , for which i then have to rotate points. so currently i can rotate points but do not know to calculate width and height after rotation.

am doing it like ...

```
// Main rotation function
     function rotate(originX, originY,pointX, pointY, angle) {
        angle = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
            x: Math.cos(angle) * (pointX-originX) - Math.sin(angle) * (pointY-originY) + originX,
            y: Math.sin(angle) * (pointX-originX) + Math.cos(angle) * (pointY-originY) + originY
        };
    }

   // initial Rectangle 
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   var x = 200
   var y = 200
   var w = 80
   var h = 20
   var angle = 90 ;
   ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

   // Calculate Center
   var cx = (x + (w/2));
   var cy = (y + (h/2));

    // highlight Center
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(cx,cy, 5, 5);

    // Rotate starting x y at angle xxx
   var r =  rotate(cx,cy,x,y, angle - h );

    // highlight roate points
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(r.x, r.y, 5, 5);


    // rotate Width and Height
   var r2 =  rotate(cx,cy,x+w,y+h,  angle - h ); 

      // highlight roate points
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, 5, 5);

    ctx.save();
```

so it end i rotated width and height which is ok for single line , but am interested in full rotation of width of height , like it 90 angle old with will become new height and old height will become new width. so any idea how to do it

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/047txgox/

Comment: That's quite unclear what you are after. Do you want to calculate the bounding rect of your rectangle?

Comment: @Kaiido am trying to rotate rectangle but cant recalculate its new width and height after rotation , like if we have rectangle of some width 10 and height 5 it 0 degree , if we rotate it 90 angle then its width will become 5 and height will become 10  , in fiddle you can see i have rotated points but cant set correct width and height

Comment: i tried with canvas rotate function but its not rotating on center

Comment: Not sure I'm really in a position to post an answer, but do you mean you want [something like that](https://jsfiddle.net/gv5j17f8/1)?

Comment: @Kaiido ya thanks :) something like that i also fixed it with rotate and translate function : http://jsfiddle.net/vorjcbz7/        .... can you post your answer because your one is covering everything , i will accept your answer

Comment: ah so you didn't want the bbox, but just to draw a rotated rectangle...

Comment: ya i wanted rectangle as other rotated points data i calculated. i tried earlier with rotate but it not worked so again did with translate so it worked

Comment: @Kaiido can you help a bit why i cant draw multiple rectangles correctly , single rectangle i can draw correctly , but not multiple : http://jsfiddle.net/7rwn83ss/2/

Comment: you need to reset your transformation matrix. This can be done by prepending `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` at the beginning of your function. http://jsfiddle.net/7rwn83ss/5/

Comment: ya ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) it work it 0 and 90 angle but not work it 30 , 45 angle  : http://jsfiddle.net/7rwn83ss/9/

Comment: you are doing `translate(-cx,-cx)` should be `(-cx,-cy)` You've got the same typo in your answer btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it , hope will help someone

```
   var x = 40
   var y = 80
   var w = 80
   var h = 20
   var angle = 120 ;

   // Calculate Center
   var cx = (x + (w/2));
   var cy = (y + (h/2));

context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)    
context.translate(cx, cy);
context.rotate(angle*Math.PI/180);
context.translate(-cx, -cy);
context.rect(x, y, w, h);
context.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
context.fill();

// highlight Center
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(cx,cy, 5, 5);  
context.save();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vorjcbz7/